# What are the differences between Convex Lens and Convex Mirrors?

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses

Sometimes I heard my teacher say convex 'lens' but other time I heard he say convex 'mirror'. The main problem I am currently facing right now is using the right terminology. In other words, what are the differences and similarities between a convex 'lens' and 'mirrors'? With that said, do they still behave the same like one another, if they are different? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are two different things - one is a curved mirror, while the other is a curved piece of transparent glass.

You know that light behaves differently when it falls on a flat mirror or a flat window pane. In the first case, it is reflected at an angle which corresponds to the incidence angle. In the second case, it is transmitted through the glass with an offset due to refraction inside the glass.

When both are curved, the same effects are now responsible for other phenomena: a curved mirror still reflects light, but since angle of incidence varies over the surface, the light bounces off in all directions - the image is distorted.

The light rays that enter a convex lens are refracted and leave the lens at an angle that corresponds to their radial distance from the center. Rays further outside are refracted more towards the center, and vice versa. The rays meet at a small spot behind the lens, the focal point.

[image]

In the picture above, the first two images are convex lenses, while the bottom two are convex mirrors. As you can see from the ray diagrams, the paths that rays take are completely different, and hence the image is also completely different. So it's not just a artifical distinction - *convex mirrors and lenses are two completely different things!*

Comment: Thank you, sir, but can you please just confirm 1 more thing? As the diagram you have shown above, the convex lens is converging conversely, the convex mirror is diverging, are these statement true?

Comment: Yes, a convex mirror has diverging rays, while a convex lens has converging rays.

Answer (score 0):

Mirror will reflect. Lens will transmit light.
[image]

I hope you understood.

Comment: Mr. Goli can you please go in slightly deeper than this?

Answer (score 0):

Similarities: They are both convex. Differences: The lens is transparent throughout (lets light pass through), while the mirror reflects light. You are basically asking for the difference between a lens and a mirror: Whatever their shapes, you are comparing different entities.

But let us now compare the behaviors of the convex mirror and convex lens. The convex lens will let light pass through and focus it *on the other side* of it. If you stand on one side of the lens, you can see what is on the other side of it, but distorted, depending on the distance of the objects and the position of the focal point.

The convex mirror will reflect the light *on the same side* of it. As a result, you can see what is on your side of the mirror, namely yourself, and you will look funny!

Answer (score 0):

A CONVEX mirror is opaque where convex lense is transparent .Aconvex mirror is a cause reflection of light where convex lense cause a refraction of light.
A convex mirror forms only virtual,diminished and erect image for all postion of object ,where as convex lense can form both real,inverted images of various size and virtual,erect and large iamges depending on the position of object.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the ray diagrams, the paths that rays take are completely different, and hence the image is also completely different. So it's not just a artifical distinction - convex mirrors and lenses are two completely different things!